# This code worked perfect yesterday - now it doesn't

Tags: java, string, http-post

This code worked perfectly for me. I created a html form and all the input the user would enter would all turn to strings in the java. I would use these strings and a prepared statement to enter the information into SQLite.

I got it to work, tested it out a few times and it was perfect. I then minimised my code for a few hours. I opened it again and it just stopped working. Now all the strings are "null". No idea why.

Here it the employeeDAO prepared statement:

```
 static boolean insertEmployeeAtId(String name, String gender, String dob, String address, String postcode, String natins, String title, String startdate, String salary, String email) throws SQLException {
    Employees e = new Employees();
    PreparedStatement s;

    s = connect.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO Emp_db (Name, Gender, DOB, Address, Postcode, NIN, JobTitle, StartDate, Salary, Email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");


    s.setString(1, name);
    s.setString(2, String.valueOf(gender));
    s.setString(3, dob);
    s.setString(4, address);
    s.setString(5, postcode);
    s.setString(6, natins);
    s.setString(7, title);
    s.setString(8, startdate);
    s.setString(9, salary);
    s.setString(10, email);
    return s.execute();
    }
}
```

A snippet of the html form:

```
 <form id="empForm" method="POST" action="/processEmp">
<h1 class="card-title">Add Employees</h1>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" name=\"name\" pattern="[a-zA-Z-'\s]+" required/>
</div>
```

Here is the controller that concerns the processing of the information:

```
 server.createContext("/processEmp", new HttpHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            boolean insertEmployee;
            try {
                HashMap<String, String> post = new HashMap<String, String>();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(t.getRequestBody()));
                String line = "";
                String request = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    request = request + line;
                }
                String[] pairs = request.split(
                        "&"
                );
                for
                        (
                        int
                        i = 0; i < pairs.
                        length
                        ; i++) {
                    String pair = pairs[i];
                    post.put(URLDecoder.decode(pair.split("=")[0], "UTF-8")
                            , URLDecoder.decode(pair.split("=")[1], "UTF-8"));
                }

                String EmpName = post.get("name");
                String EmpGender = post.get("gender");
                String EmpDob = post.get("dob");
                String EmpAddress = post.get("address");
                String EmpPostcode = post.get("postcode");
                String EmpNatins = post.get("natInscNo");
                String EmpTitle = post.get("title");
                String EmpStartDate = post.get("startDate");
                String EmpSalary = post.get("salary");
                String EmpEmail = post.get("email");

                String allEmp = "Name: " + EmpName + " Gender: " + EmpGender + " Dob: " + EmpDob + " Address: " + EmpAddress + " Postcode: " + EmpPostcode + " NatInscNo: " + EmpNatins + " Title: " + EmpTitle + " StartDate: " + EmpStartDate + " Salary: " + EmpSalary + " Email: " + EmpEmail;
                dao.insertEmployeeAtId(EmpName, EmpGender, EmpDob, EmpAddress, EmpPostcode, EmpNatins, EmpTitle, EmpStartDate, EmpSalary, EmpEmail);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new
                        OutputStreamWriter(t.getResponseBody()));
                out.write("Result = ");
                out.write(String.valueOf(allEmp));
                t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
                out.close();
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    server.setExecutor(null); // default implementation of threading
    server.start();
    System.out.println("The server is up and running on port 8005");
}
```

I would rather know why it sopped working and how to fix it then use another method to get the imput values from html into a string in java. Any form of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the first thing I'd check is that the values are still in `post`.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? I'm fairly knew, sorry if the questions are silly.

Comment: I mean the `post` variable in the `handle` method.  Does it contain the correct information?  You pretty much want to backtrack this and see where the failure is.  If this variable contains the correct values, you know the problem is somewhere after that point.  If it does not, you know the problem is before that point.

Comment: It must be correct because this very code was working last night. I have no idea how to make it work again.

Comment: is it possible that your HTML changed?  I mean, obviously something changed.  Maybe you changed your HTML a while back and then forgot to refresh, so the problem didn't show until now.

Comment: I pressed undo until I was on the stage before I initially got it to work. I then pressed redo and tested each time until I went back to the latest edit. It was as if it never worked, but I still have the info in my SQLite, so I know for a fact that it did work at one point.

Comment: If the behavior changed, then something in the product or its environment changed. It is mathematically impossible that nothing changed. So the question is, what changed?